# How to change data type of column when columns comes from multiple table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have get these column from `information_schema`. Now I want to change postcode datatype from nvarchar to int but these column in different table.

[image: pic]

Comment: Assuming that everything that starts with a v in the table_name column is actually a view, then all I see is only one table...

Comment: When posting questions, please take a moment to ensure everything is readable and presented carefully. Also, please do not add any requests for urgency - volunteers will get around to questions they like at their leisure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the below query in SSMS and Paste the result.

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_NAME+' ALTER COLUMN POSTCODE INT  
GO
'   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='POSTCODE'
```

You will see all alters in one with different Table names.

I have added go Statement for every Alter.

And also take a look at [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to know how to ask a good question.

Comment: suppose i have 20 table where column name is postcode then i will write this query 20 times its very lengthy........... do I understand correctly that...

Comment: There is no way to alter all tables with a single select. But the above statement will generate all alters in a single result set. You just need to copy the result, paste it in ssms and hit F5 @rajeshnegi

Comment: And no need of writing the above query 20 times. Just one time execution to generate alter code for all tables. @rajeshnegi

Comment: Your welcome. accept the answer if its helpful. @rajeshnegi